# Cannot add System.Net.Http reference to Xamarin.iOS Library project

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin's Visual Studio pluggin.  I have a Xamarin iOS Library project and it needs to use System.Net.Http in order to compile.  However, I cannot seem to add it as a reference.  I have updated my Xamarin Studio to the Alpha version, but still cannot see System.Net.Http in the Assemblies list when attempting to Add Reference.

Any help here would be GREATLY appreciated as I am inches away from getting this thing implemented, but am stuck on this one reference.

Is this available in Visual Studio (with Xamarin Pluggin installed), or is it only in Xamarin Studio?

Thanks in advance for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOW !!  What a work around.

Ok, here's the solution.  Looks like the Visual Studio pluggin does NOT get updated when you update Xamarin Studio on your windows box.  HOWEVER, when you go to your mac build server and update Xamarin to the Alpha version, then open a Xamarin Project in Visual Studio, it will prompt you that the build server and Pluggin are different versions and will allow you to upgrade.  When you upgrade, after closing visual studio, then open visual studio again, VOILA!!!  The System.Net.Http reference is now available under Assemblies when adding a reference.

So, the solution is to update your MAC Xamarin Studio to the Alpha version and then Visual Studio will prompt you for an update.  Update it and you're golden !!

Seems like there should be an easier way, but this one worked.

Comment: Yeah, I have had issues with update not working in VS as well.

Answer (score -1):

i think you cant add The System.Net.Http reference.you should try this RestSharp
A simple REST client for consuming HTTP APIs..

RestSharp makes it easy to consume the wide array of services on the web over HTTP, like: Amazon, Facebook, or even Twitter...

http://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp

Comment: You can add System.Net.Http, but from the Xamarin library.

Comment: I've used both and prefer HttpClient since it returns a Task that can be awaited.